# Adding to List inside a Using block

Tags: c#, collections, dispose, idisposable, using

I have a class which implements IDisposable like such

```
  public class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    private IList<string> _someList = new List<string>();

    public IList<string> SomeList
    {
        get { return _someList; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _someList = null;
    }
}
```

and a method that uses 'using' blocks to create two instances of this class and add it to a collection like such

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IList<SomeClass> classes = new List<SomeClass>();

        using (var sc = new SomeClass())
        {
            sc.SomeList.Add("a");
            classes.Add(sc);
        }

        using (var sc = new SomeClass())
        {
            sc.SomeList.Add("b");
            classes.Add(sc);
        }

        foreach (var a in classes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.SomeList[0]);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Whats happening here is by the time i come to the foreach to iterate through my elements in "classes" the "SomeList" property of both my objects are null.

I do understand that since each using executes Dispose() and in the dispose, i AM null-ing the two lists, they will be null.

My question is how do i achieve this without having to stop null-ing "SomeList" inside my dispose().

thanks

--UPDATE 1

Something closer to real code

```
base.OnPreRender(e);

    Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
    HtmlHead head = (HtmlHead)page.Header;

    if (Settings.AreSet)
    {
        using (var noIndex = new HtmlMeta())
        {
            noIndex.Name = "somename";
            noIndex.Content = "somecontent";

            head.Controls.AddAt(0, noIndex);
        }
    }

    using (var machineName = new HtmlMeta())
    {
        machineName.Name = "somename2";
        machineName.Content = "somecontent2";

        head.Controls.AddAt(1, machineName);
    }

    UpdateHeader(head);
```

--UPDATE #2 
A variant of the above class with a string property now, as opposed to a a list.

```
public class SomeClass2 : IDisposable
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SomeString = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

It still does the same thing for the following method. My 'classes' contains lists of 'SomeClass2' which has 'SomeString' as empty (what i set in my dispose())

```
IList<SomeClass2> classes = new List<SomeClass2>();

        using (var sc = new SomeClass2())
        {
            sc.SomeString = "a";
            classes.Add(sc);
        }

        using (var sc = new SomeClass2())
        {
            sc.SomeString = "a";
            classes.Add(sc);
        }

        foreach (var a in classes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.SomeString);
        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: My question is, why would you want to null the list in `Dispose`? That's not what `Dispose` is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `Dispose` to be called? Just don't use `using` statement.

Or move the entire logic inside `using`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<SomeClass> classes = new List<SomeClass>();

    using (var sc = new SomeClass())
    {
        sc.SomeList.Add("a");
        classes.Add(sc);

        using (var sc = new SomeClass())
         {
            sc.SomeList.Add("b");
            classes.Add(sc);

            foreach (var a in classes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.SomeList[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Btw: looks like using `IDisposable` in that case is pointless. GC would gather unused `List<T>` objects anyway.

Comment: :) i know it is pointless in this example. but this example is a simplification of a code block that we have in production. It is not possible to 1. return  from inside 'using' 2. we need a populated list AFTER the 'using' block (and the Dispose() method will do somthing similar, like null-ing a list)

Comment: @nesh_s Could you provide something closer to the real code? The code you have now just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @KendallFrey My updates above. Also if i may ask WHY does the first sample doesnt make sense? I am trying to find a way to dispose a list inside a class while retaining a copy of it in my collection.

Comment: You can't dispose a list, and keeping a copy of it won't cause any problems.

Comment: @KendallFrey Ok. Please see update -2. I have changed my class to have string property. I am disposing THAT now in dispose(). Still when i go through the same motions again, the 'classes' list contains 'Someclass2' which has 'SomeString' property as null.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with just copying the string before it's disposed.

Comment: You should `Dispose` object only when you don't need it anymore. And in all your examples you really need the object later, so you can't dispose it. So you have to either expand `using` scope or get rid of it.

Comment: Ofcourse its not about having a problem in copying a string. What i am after is something that i can use when i have classes composed of other classes, and i selectively want to dispose those properties. Also before posting this question I did fully understand that the only option i may have is to create a COPY of the object BEFORE i dispose. I was looking for a better option, if there exists any